# Retrieve words based on a given context For example, given a job description, I need to find the words related to the skills

Tags: pandas, machine-learning, nlp, computer-science, data-science

I have a paragraph of job description as below

JAVA SOLUTION ARCHITECT â€“ CONTRACT â€“ DALLAS, TXA leading consulting firm is looking to bring on a Java Solution Architect to help them deliver a project and work closely with their Principle Architect. The engagement is going to entail either re-platforming or a rewrite of the end clientâ€™s existing application that is running on an Oracle platform with Pentaho utilized as the BI tool depending on what is uncovered after further investigation into their end-clientâ€™s application.Java Solution Architect Strong experience working as a Solution Architect with a strong Java background- In addition to strong Java experience, well-rounded knowledge of other technologies such as open source BI tools, .net, c#, or even devops.Â - Strong BI project experience â€“ working with not all of but tools such as: hanna, cognos, SSAS, ETL, microstrategy- Spring- Java- Oracle- strong back end development experienceÂ - Anything similar to hibernate- PentahoFollow us on our BLOG to see more jobs like this: http://dallas.vereduscorp.com /Â Why Veredus?Candidates work with a professional Recruiter whose average experience is eight years in the industry.

And I want to fetch all the skills for this job description such as,

['Oracle platform with Pentaho', 
'Strong experience working as a Solution Architect with a strong Java background',
'well-rounded knowledge of other technologies such as open source BI tools, .net, c#, or even devops',
'Strong BI project experience ',
'hanna, cognos, SSAS, ETL, microstrategy- Spring- Java- Oracle- strong back end development experience',
'hibernate- Pentaho']

I searched a lot but I could not solve this problem. Any help is appreciated.

I searched and I am not clear on how to approach this. I am new to NLP field.